# find aria-label in html page using soup python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, find

i have html pages, with this code :

`<span itemprop="title" data-andiallelmwithtext="15" aria-current="page" aria-label="you in page
number 452">page 452</span>`

i want to find the aria-label, so i have tried this:

```
is_452 = soup.find("span", {"aria-label": "you in page number 452"})
print(is_452)
```

i want to get the result :

```
is_452 =page 452
```

i'm getting the result:

```
is_452=none
```

how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the desired element is a dynamic element and you can use [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to extract the *value* of the **aria-label** attribute inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section#header a.cart-heading[href='/cart']"))).get_attribute("aria-label"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@id='header']//a[@class='cart-heading' and @href='/cart']"))).get_attribute("aria-label"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: i can't work with driver . can i get this data by doing request to the url ?

Answer (score 1):

It has line breaks in it, so it doesn't match through text.Try the following

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''<span itemprop="title" data-andiallelmwithtext="15" aria-current="page" aria-label="you in page
number 452">page 452</span>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
is_452 = doc.getElementByReg('aria-label="you in page[\s]*number 452"',tag="span")
print (is_452.text)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i'm getting exception all the time

Comment: There is a problem with one version. If you can run it before and update it later, you may have used the problematic version. I have modified the above code, or you can update the library. Please try again. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: what should be in html ?  i'm doing it like this : 'soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")' and then 'oc = SimplifiedDoc(soup)'

Comment: Simplifieddoc has only one parameter and does not depend on other libraries. SimplifiedDoc(res.text) Here's an example: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

The reason soup fails in doing this is because of the line break. I have a simpler solution which doesn't use any separate library, just BeautifulSoup only. I know this question is old, but it has 1k views so it's clear many people search up this question.
You can use triple-quote strings to take into account the newline.
This:

```
is_452 = soup.find("span", {"aria-label": "you in page number 452"})
print(is_452)
```

Would become:

```
search_label = """you in page
number 452"""
is_452 = soup.find("span", {"aria-label": search_label})
print(is_452)
```